# If non-conservative force is constant then is the work done by it independent of the path taken?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, conservative-field

Here, does the writer mean conservative forces, because I think non-conservative forces do depend on path taken.

[image]

Comment: -1 I think your question is inconsistent : a non-conservative force is one for which the work done **does** depend on the path taken. If the work done **does not** depend on the path then the force is conservative. You are asking "If a force for which work done is not independent of path is also constant, then is the work which it does independent of path?" In basic logic, "If X does not have property Y but does have property Z, then does X have property Y?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the work done by non-conservative forces depend on the path taken, but a constant force is trivially conservative.

For a constant force $\vec F = a \hat x + b \hat y + c \hat z$, simply define a potential $U = -(ax + by +cz)$.  Easy peasy.

I would imagine that you are thinking of something like kinetic friction, which *seems* constant enough, if not for the fact that it depends on the magnitude and direction of the object's velocity.

Comment: got it first.....

Comment: Understanding your solution is,Easy peasy:)

Answer (score 2):

If a force is constant, then it is inherently conservative.  More precisely, the condition that a force be conservative is:

$${\vec \nabla} \times {\vec F} = 0$$

However, since the curl of a vector is ultimately a bunch of partial derivatives, for any constant force field, the curl will be zero.  Therefore, all constant forces are conservative, which means the net work done will always be path-independent.